# Linq group by Titem a list of Ditem which each contains a collection of Titem

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of devices. For each device of this list, I have an inner list of zones. I want to group each device by zone, but I don't know how to do that in Linq, I want to get an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, DeviceModel>>` as output.

The string if the zonename in my ZoneModel.

My device class:

```
public class DeviceModel
{
        public List<ZoneModel> Zones { get; set; }
        public string Serial { get; set; }
}
```

My Zone class:

```
public class ZoneModel
{
        public string ZoneName { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I need to get a enumerable of group device by zone with this code:

```
List<DeviceModel> deviceList = new List<DeviceModel>();

... (device filled by some code)

IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, DeviceModel>> deviceByZoneGroups =
        from dataInfo in listDatas.Where(d => d.Zones != null && d.Zone.Any())
        group dataInfo by dataInfo.Zones into zoneGroup
        orderby zoneGroup.Key
        select zoneGroup;
```

Comment: Please show the code

Comment: [mre], a simple list of 4-5 items, with 2 group max, with class définition and initialisation. 
And any kind of representation for the expected result.

Comment: @MichaelMao done for code part

Comment: @DragandDrop done for correction

Comment: @AdrienRuffie I have a complete answer for you listed below. If that is correct, please mark it as the answer and upvote it. Let me know if you have further questions, and I'll be happy to help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to group objects based on unique items in a property list.

This solution 1st uses a `SelectMany` overload that ties back the original object to the expanded property list to achieve the grouping you are asking for. It flattens out the lists of Zones that belongs to each Device in one list. But with the overload, it maintains the relationship to it's original parent object. It basically reverses the relationship from Device with many Zones to Zone with many Devices.

Then 2nd it uses an overload of GroupBy which allows you to map each result of the grouping, so that only a list of Device objects is returned. This maps `IGrouping<string, anonymous type<string, DeviceModel>>` to `IGrouping<string, DeviceModel>` which is what you asked for.

This should be your complete answer:

```
void Main()
{
    // Setup some test data
    var devices = GetTestData();

    // The main solution
    var group = devices
        .SelectMany(d => d.Zones, (device, zone) =>
            new
            {
                ZoneName = zone.ZoneName,
                Device = device
            })
        .GroupBy(d => d.ZoneName, x => x.Device);

    // Just for visibility
    group
        .Select(d => $"{d.Key}::{(string.Join(",", d.Select(x => x.Serial)))}")
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

    // This returns:
    //      Living Room::12,34
    //      Entryway::12,56
}

public class DeviceModel
{
    public List<ZoneModel> Zones { get; set; }
    public string Serial { get; set; }
}

public class ZoneModel
{
    public string ZoneName { get; set; }
}

public static List<DeviceModel> GetTestData()
{
    return
        new List<DeviceModel>
        {
            new DeviceModel
            {
                Serial = "12",
                Zones = new List<ZoneModel>
                    {
                        new ZoneModel { ZoneName = "Living Room" },
                        new ZoneModel { ZoneName = "Entryway" },
                    }
            },
            new DeviceModel
            {
                Serial = "34",
                Zones = new List<ZoneModel>
                    {
                        new ZoneModel { ZoneName = "Living Room" }
                    }
            },
            new DeviceModel
            {
                Serial = "56",
                Zones = new List<ZoneModel>
                    {
                        new ZoneModel { ZoneName = "Entryway" }
                    }

            }
        };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SelectMany and GroupBy

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, DeviceModel>> GetGrouped(IEnumerable<DeviceModel> deviceModels)
    => deviceModels.SelectMany(i => i.Zones.Select(j => new { j.ZoneName, i })).GroupBy(i => i.ZoneName, i => i.i);
```